# Issue Selecting DB value from DropDown List when Page is generated

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0

I have a GV and I need to dynamically build a list of users who have had active DB Writes in the last 180 days. One page gets the Membership Identity Username and writes it to 
Table1. I then do a SELECT Distinct on that table to populate a DDL and write that value to Table2.  The Problem is when I try to set the DDL Selected value via `SelectedValue='<%# Bind("DeliverPartTo") %>'` I get:

> > 'DDL_DeliverPartTo' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
> >     Parameter name: value

Here is the code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DeliverPartTo" SortExpression="DeliverPartTo">
                <ItemTemplate>                         
                     <asp:DropDownList ID="DDL_DeliverPartTo" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("DeliverPartTo") %>'                            DataSourceID="SQLTechs" DataTextField="RequestedBy" DataValueField="RequestedBy" 
                        Height="25px" Width="135px" AutoPostBack="True"  AppendDataBoundItems="true" 
                        OnDataBound="SqlDS_DeliverPartTo_DataBinding" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DDL_DeliverPartTo_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                        >
                        <asp:ListItem Text="" Enabled="true" Selected="True" Value='-1'></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Stock" Enabled="true" Value='-1'></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                     <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SQLTechs" runat="server" 
                        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:inventory_v2ConnectionString %>"
                        SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [RequestedBy] FROM [Process_PartRequests]">
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>
                </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField> 



 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" 
            runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:inventory_v2ConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT Process_WarrantyTracker.ID, Process_WarrantyTracker.RequestNumber, Process_PartRequests.DateRequested, Process_RequestStatuses.ID AS StatusID, 
                         Process_RequestStatuses.StatusCode, Process_PartRequests.CATicketNumber, Process_PartRequests.SystemSerialNumber, 
                         Models_PriModels.PriModel + '-' + Models_SecModels.SecModel + '-' + Models_FormFactor.Form AS Model, Part_Catalog.OEMPartCode, 
                         Part_Groups.GroupType + ' - ' + Part_Groups.GroupName AS Groups, Process_PartRequests.RequestedBy, Models_OEMs.Manufacturer AS OEM, 
                         Process_WarrantyTracker.DateOrderedFromOEM, Process_WarrantyTracker.OrderedByICGAdmin, Process_WarrantyTracker.OEMWorkOrderNumber, 
                         Process_WarrantyTracker.PartSerialNumber, Process_WarrantyTracker.OrderRecievedDate, Process_WarrantyTracker.DeliverPartTo, 
                         Process_WarrantyTracker.ProblemFlag, Process_WarrantyTracker.PartOfMultiPartOrder, Process_WarrantyTracker.ShipperTrackingNo, 
                         Process_WarrantyTracker.ReturnOrderShipped, Process_WarrantyTracker.Comment1, Process_WarrantyTracker.Comment2
FROM            Process_WarrantyTracker INNER JOIN
                         Process_PartRequests ON Process_WarrantyTracker.RequestNumber = Process_PartRequests.RequestNumber INNER JOIN
                         Process_RequestStatuses ON Process_PartRequests.RequestStatus = Process_RequestStatuses.ID INNER JOIN
                         Models ON Process_PartRequests.Model = Models.ID INNER JOIN
                         Models_FormFactor ON Models.FormFactor = Models_FormFactor.ID INNER JOIN
                         Models_OEMs ON Models.Manufacturer = Models_OEMs.ID INNER JOIN
                         Models_PriModels ON Models.PriModel = Models_PriModels.ID INNER JOIN
                         Models_SecModels ON Models.SecModel = Models_SecModels.ID INNER JOIN
                         Part_Catalog ON Process_PartRequests.OEMPartCode = Part_Catalog.ID INNER JOIN
                         Part_Groups ON Part_Catalog.GroupType = Part_Groups.ID
                         WHERE Process_RequestStatuses.ID != 4">

        </asp:SqlDataSource>
protected void SqlDS_DeliverPartTo_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        GridViewRow gr = (GridViewRow)((DataControlFieldCell)((DropDownList)sender).Parent).Parent;
        HiddenField RequestNumber = (HiddenField)gr.FindControl("RequestNumber");
        string ReqNum = RequestNumber.Value;
        string query = "SELECT [DeliverPartTo] FROM [Process_WarrantyTracker] WHERE [RequestNumber] = @RequestNumber ";
        DropDownList DDL_DeliverPartTo = (DropDownList)GridView1.FindControl("DDL_DeliverPartTo");
        SqlConnection connectionString = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["inventory_v2ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        connectionString.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connectionString);
        Object returnValue;
        cmd.CommandText = query;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RequestNumber", ReqNum);
        cmd.Connection = connectionString;            
        returnValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        connectionString.Close();
        DDL_DeliverPartTo.SelectedValue = returnValue.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
}
protected void DDL_DeliverPartTo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow gr = (GridViewRow)((DataControlFieldCell)((DropDownList)sender).Parent).Parent;
    DropDownList DDL_DeliverPartTo = (DropDownList)gr.FindControl("DDL_DeliverPartTo");
    HiddenField RequestNumber = (HiddenField)gr.FindControl("RequestNumber");
    string ReqNum = RequestNumber.Value;
    string query = "UPDATE [Process_WarrantyTracker] SET [DeliverPartTo]=@DeliverPartTo WHERE [RequestNumber] = @RequestNumber ";
    SqlConnection connectionString = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["inventory_v2ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connectionString);
    cmd.Connection.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DeliverPartTo", DDL_DeliverPartTo.SelectedValue);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@RequestNumber", ReqNum);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    Object ddlValues;
    ddlValues = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    cmd.Connection.Close();
    cmd.Connection.Dispose();
    Response.Redirect("Admin-WarrantyTracker.aspx");

}
```

Comment: `Text` is not a property of `DropDownList`.

Comment: Oops, that was a bad copy/paste. It should have been SelectedValue='<%# Bind("DeliverPartTo") %>' which results in the described issue.

Comment: Your error message is telling you that you have an item you are trying to set as selected that is not in your DropDownList. Have you verified that all possibilities for `DeliverPartTo` are in your DDL?

Comment: Another thing... You should only be setting `SelectedValue` once. Either in your code-front or code-behind. Not both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SelectedValue doesnot work in this way. Instead of `DDL_DeliverPartTo.SelectedValue = returnValue.ToString();` try:

```
DDL_DeliverPartTo.SelectedIndex = DDL_DeliverPartTo.Items.IndexOf(DDL_DeliverPartTo.Items.FindByValue(returnValue.ToString()));
```

**EDIT:** You have to find the control in GridView_RowDataBound and in datarow. Try the code below:

```
void GridView1_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        try
        {
            GridViewRow gr = e.Row;
            HiddenField RequestNumber = (HiddenField)gr.FindControl("RequestNumber");
            string ReqNum = RequestNumber.Value;
            string query = "SELECT [DeliverPartTo] FROM [Process_WarrantyTracker] WHERE [RequestNumber] = @RequestNumber ";
            DropDownList DDL_DeliverPartTo = (DropDownList)gr.FindControl("DDL_DeliverPartTo");
            SqlConnection connectionString = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["inventory_v2ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            connectionString.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connectionString);
            Object returnValue;
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RequestNumber", ReqNum);
            cmd.Connection = connectionString;
            returnValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            connectionString.Close();
           DDL_DeliverPartTo.SelectedIndex = DDL_DeliverPartTo.Items.IndexOf(DDL_DeliverPartTo.Items.FindByValue(returnValue.ToString()));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Still blank when I try that in OnDataBound or OnDataBinding.

Comment: Well, that would make way more sense than what I was trying to do :D Thanks!